# How to stop cursor from jumping to beginning/end of textbox on up/down key?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I prevent the cursor from jumping to the beginning or end of a textbox when up or down arrow key is pressed, using JavaScript and jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<input type="text" />
```

```
$("input:text").keydown(function(e){
   if(e.which == 38 || e.which == 40) 
       e.preventDefault();
});
```

You can prevent default on the up and down arrow keys.

http://jsfiddle.net/C5ZCE/

Comment: And that's all she wrote. Thanks!